# Bootstrap 3 Navigation Bar toggle button with no function

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, business-catalyst

I am working in the latest version of Bootstrap 3 and I have made and customized a navigation bar for my website [that can be found here](http://upgradeck.businesscatalyst.com/). I can't seem to find why, when I re-size my browser window to mobile device size, that the collapse button does not work. Can you work out why the button has no function?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
  font-family: Raleway;
}
footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 170, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(64, 179, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #0066cc;
  color: #0099ff;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #0066cc;
  color: #0099ff;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #0066cc;
  color: #004080;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #0099ff;
  color: #004080;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="/StyleSheets/ModuleStyleSheets.css" rel="StyleSheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var jslang = 'EN';
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <div id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="pull-left">
          <img src="http://www.coding-kids.net/logo.png" width="180px">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="tutorials"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> TUTORIALS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="faq"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> FAQs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    &copy; Coding Kids 2016. All rights reserved.
  </footer>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include jQuery before Bootstrap like this:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
  font-family: Raleway;
}
footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 170, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(64, 179, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #0066cc;
  color: #0099ff;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #0066cc;
  color: #0099ff;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #0066cc;
  color: #004080;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #0099ff;
  color: #004080;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="/StyleSheets/ModuleStyleSheets.css" rel="StyleSheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var jslang = 'EN';
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <div id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="pull-left">
          <img src="http://www.coding-kids.net/logo.png" width="180px">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="tutorials"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> TUTORIALS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="faq"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> FAQs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    &copy; Coding Kids 2016. All rights reserved.
  </footer>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change order to bootstrap js file

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
  font-family: Raleway;
}
footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 170, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(64, 179, 255, 1);
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #0066cc;
  color: #0099ff;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #0066cc;
  color: #0099ff;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #0066cc;
  color: #004080;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #0099ff;
  color: #004080;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="/StyleSheets/ModuleStyleSheets.css" rel="StyleSheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var jslang = 'EN';
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <div id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="pull-left">
          <img src="http://www.coding-kids.net/logo.png" width="180px">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="tutorials"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> TUTORIALS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="faq"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> FAQs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    &copy; Coding Kids 2016. All rights reserved.
  </footer>

  </body>
```